# Javascript document.querySelectorAll get tags with specific class but without a specific attribute

Tags: javascript

How can have a list of tags with a specific class but without a specific attribute?

```js
var sentenceTrans = document.querySelectorAll('.trans-lang:not[data-translation="translated"]'); 
// but this doesn't work
```

Comment: either give a new class or loop though `sentenceTrans` and check for attributes

Comment: the :not() selector uses round brackets rather than square ones